# C++11 regex_match does not match what it must

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2012, c++11

```
std::string pattern = "[disk0-9]";

std::regex regex(pattern, std::regex::ECMAScript);


std::string subject = "Disk1";

bool result = std::regex_match(subject, regex, std::regex_constants::match_any);


std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Please, why `regex_match` return false?

Comment: Because you're searching for a lowercase `d` in the character class and the actual string starts with a capital `D`.

Comment: if I change to std::string pattern = "[Disk0-9]"; it sadly return false;

Comment: It should return true because it matches `i`.

Comment: Shoot, hold on. The whole pattern is in a character class :-) You only need the character class for variable characters such as the numbers in this case. Thus the correct pattern should be `Disk[0-9]`. Or you can replace `[0-9]` with the shorthand `\d`.

Comment: mart1n thank you!!! with pattern = "[Dd]isk[0-9]" works!!! please answer and I'll check it;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comments, correct answer should be (including the variable case of the letter D):

```
pattern = "[Dd]isk[0-9]"
```

Answer (score 5):

Fix your code as following:

```
std::string pattern = "disk[0-9]";
std::regex regex(pattern, std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase); //Ignore Case
```